# How do I add time to a date in unix shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a file that contains date values. I want to be able to pull the last line of the file, formatted like "'2018-09-18 16:42:57'" add 1 day to it and store that into a variable. The code I have right now looks like the following, but it does not work:

```
start_date=$(tail -n 1 run_dates.txt)
start_date=$(start_date -d "+1 day")
```

What is the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49053/156990

Comment: Showing the specific error you're having with prior approaches would be a good place to start. If the error message tells us you're trying to use commands meant for GNU `date` but you don't have that version, that gives us enough information to actually provide a useful answer. Right now, there's no specific problem here, so all we can do is guess.

Comment: *"...but it does not work"* is not a good problem statement. Please show the variable values and explain how it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one-liner `gnu date` command to extract last line of the file, add one day and store output in a variable:

```
start_date=$(date -d "$(tail -n 1 run_dates.txt) +1 day" '+%Y-%m-%d %T')
```

To check variable content use:

```
declare -p start_date
```

```
declare -- s="2018-09-19 11:42:57"
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting the GNUisms.

Comment: Thanks that's fair point (edited)